# error in value excel error while using a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I would like to find **the number of dead black cats** in the following table using excel formula.

```
Column B   Column C    Column D      Column E
(Animal)   (Color)      (DOB)      (DateOfDeath)
  Cat       Black     03/08/2010    03/08/2015
  Cat       White     03/08/2010
  Cat       Black     03/08/2010    03/08/2015
  Dog       White     03/08/2015    03/08/2015
  Dog       White     03/08/2015    03/08/2015
  Cow       Black     03/08/2015    
  Cat       Black     03/08/2015    
  Cat       White     03/08/2016
```

The formula which I used is:

```
=AGGREGATE(2, 6, (B3:B10="Cat")*(C3:C10="Black")*(NOT(ISBLANK(E3:E10))))
```

For some reason, it is not working, I don't know what mistake I have made.

Answer (score 1):

Since the argument (B3:B10="Cat")*(C3:C10="Black")*(NOT(ISBLANK(E3:E10))) is equivalent to an array of 0 and 1, you could just sum it.

```
{=SUM((B3:B10="Cat")*(C3:C10="Black")*(NOT(ISBLANK(E3:E10))))}
```

ctrl + shift + enter to evaluate SUM as an array formula (adding the {} brackets)

Answer (score 0):

You can derive it by `Total Number of Black Cats` - `Total No of Black Cats with empty DateofDeath`

`=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"Black",A2:A9,"Cat") - COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"Black",A2:A9,"Cat",D2:D9,"")`

Alternative Direct Method would be
`=COUNTIFS(B:B,"Cat",C:C,"Black",E:E,"<>")`

Comment: @pnuts , You are correct. `<>` didnt strike my mind and thats more direct method

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with the Aggregate function yet, looking at it though it seems to not necessarily fit what you are trying to do.  I would recommend to use the countifs function instead.

```
            =COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$9,AnimalType,$C$2:$C$9,AnimalColor,$E$2:$E$9,">0")
```

This function evaluates each criteria, in columns B, C, and D against AnimalType, AnimalColor, and whether the date is greater than zero.  I duplicated the data set and entered the formula which generated the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that not all aggregate functions handle arrays (only function numbers 14  and above handle arrays).

2nd - you cannot mutply trues and falses. You need to conver them to number values first by adding -- in front.

If you would like to do this calculation using arrays I'd suggest using this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B3:B10="Cat")*--(C3:C10="Black")*--(NOT(ISBLANK(E3:E10))))
```

Otherwise Use COUNTIFS as suggested by the above poster.